# Different answer types in questionnaire organisation

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to implement a questionnaire application. Here is my question model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    TEXT = 0
    CHECKBOX = 1
    INTEGER = 2

    QUESTION_TYPES = (
        (TEXT, 'Text'),
        (CHECKBOX, 'CheckBox'),
        (INTEGER, 'Integer'),
    )
question_type = models.IntegerField(default=TEXT, choices=QUESTION_TYPES)
text = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
```

And the answer type has to be based on the question. So, I want it to be IntegerField for INTEGER, CharField for TEXT, etc.

I had an idea to make abstract Answer class and IntegerAnswer, TextAnswer inherited from it. But this way is not very convenient for editing in admin.

How can I implement Answer class better?